# ExtJS6: how to create a package extending Ext.field.TextArea

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am creating a ExtJS 6 package to reuse a library across my extjs app. I need to extend `Ext.field.TextArea` functionality. could someone have a simple example to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
Ext.define('MyPackage.form.field.MyTextArea', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.field.TextArea',

  xtype: 'my-textarea'

});
```

And in your `package.json` verify you've got the following values:

```
"type": "code",

"toolkit": "classic",
```

Comment: that throws `Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.field.TextArea`